# Changing font size of attributed text in UITextView takes a lot of time in iOS 6 using Xcode 5

Tags: ios, ios6, xcode5, uitextview, uifont

I am developing an application that target iOS6+.

I have a text view with with large attributed text. Maybe 1000 lines odd lines red color and other lines green color.

I use below code for changing the font size of the textview:

```
self.doaTextView.editable= YES;
self.doaTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.FontSilder.value];
self.doaTextView.editable= NO;
```

but it takes much time. It is about 2 second on iOS 7 and about 5-10 second on iOS 6!!!

(I enable and disable `editable` feature, becasue if I do not do this the changes not appear in iOS 6. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19168661/1939409))

What is the problem?

**Edit**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289481/uitextview-setting-font-size-of-attributedtext-slow?rq=1) topic related to this problem too. Really there is not any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this problem by recreating my `attributedtext` again and setting it as a new `attributedtext` to my `uitextview`.